# how to increase internet speed on a particular computer in a LAN network?

Tags: internet

I am using internet in a LAN network of about 30 PC's.Every PC is connected to internet and is using considerable speed.So my questions is weather there is a way to increase internet speed or downloading speed on a particular node which is not the server from that non-server node itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes and No, you can't increase past your bandwidth limit but you can reserve part of the bandwidth for particular machines. This would depend on your network configuration, firewall/router/switches etc

Comment: @Drifter104 Yes i want to use the maximum available bandwidth on that node.Please provide how can i do it?

Comment: I can't possibly answer that with information you have in the question. You need to look at doing QoS (Quality of Service) for your particular router/firewall/switch